# Oracle Apex - Link created from Link Builder not pushing full value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am currently using Oracle Apex version 18.1.0.00.45 and I am struggling with the Link Builder feature of a column in the Interactive grid.

I have created a simple table with one column (labeled Column1) to demonstrate the problem. From this table, I have created an Interactive Grid. I then created a Text Field item in the page. The goal is to make the text in each row of the column a "Link" that when clicked pushes the text in that row of the column to the Text Field. I changed the "Type" of Column1 in the column attributes to "Link". I used the Link Builder in the column attributes to create the link. In the Link Builder in the Target section I set the "Type" to "Page in this application". I set the "Page" to the current page that contains the IG and text field. In the Link Builder in the Set Items section I set the name to the name of the Text Field item on the page. I set the value to &COLUMN1.

Here is a view of my Interactive Grid and Text Field:

[image]

Here is a view of my Link Builder:

[image]

The problem: When I click on the links in the rows that contain text with no commas (rows 1-5), the full text in that row is pushed to the text field perfectly. For example, when I click on the link in row 3, "word1 word2 word3" is pushed and subsequently displayed in the text field. However, when I click on any of the links that contain text with commas (rows 6-10), only the text that comes before the comma is pushed and subsequently displayed in the text field. For example, when I click on the link in row 8, "word1 word2" is pushed and subsequently displayed in the text field (note: the comma after word2 is not pushed either), instead of "word1 word2 word3".

Here is what I view when I click on the link in row 3:

[image]

Here is what I view when I click on the link in row 8:

[image]

Does anyone know why this problem is occurring?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to escape the link, look at this: https://stewstools.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/apex-column-linking-with-data-that-includes-commas/

Comment: Thank you very much, romeuBraga. That fixes my problem!

Comment: Instead of redirecting to the page (causing the whole page to load), have you considered using javascript instead, e.g. `javascript:$s("P402_TEXTFIELD","&COLUMN1.")` - this would avoid the page reload. You could then have a dynamic action on the text field that refreshes just the report.